# Как применить transform-origin к позиции блока?

Tags: javascript, css3

Я пытаюсь сделать перемещение блока мышкой, и он движется, но когда я пытаюсь переместить блок за границы экрана он не перемещается за границу дальше чем на половину своей высоты/ширины т.к. при клике по блоку он перемещает свой центр в место клика. transform-origin не помогает.

В HTML только табличка в div.

```
table = document.querySelector("table");
press = 0;
table.addEventListener("mousedown", (e)=>{
    press =1;
    e.currentTarget.style.transformOrigin = `${e.clientX}px ${e.clientY}px`;
    e.currentTarget.addEventListener("mousemove", function move(e){
        if(press==1){
            e.currentTarget.style.transform = `translateX(${e.clientX-0.5*e.currentTarget.offsetWidth}px) translateY(${e.clientY-0.5*e.currentTarget.offsetHeight}px)`;
        }
        e.currentTarget.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=>{
            press=0;
        });
    });
});
scale = document.querySelector("input[type='range']");
scale.addEventListener("input",()=>{
    table.style.fontSize = scale.value+"em";
});
```

Comment: При каждом `mousedown` нужно находить координаты нажатия мыши внутри блока - `dx = e.x - левая координата блока`, `dy = e.y - верхняя координата блока` и затем при движении мыши отнимать их - `e.x - dx`, `e.y - dy`

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ я применил эти значения к transform-origin и всёравно не работает
e.currentTarget.style.transformOrigin = `${e.x}px ${e.y}px`

Comment: я вроде не говорил что эти значения нужно к  `transform-origin` применять

Comment: @ᅠhᅠтак тоже не работает

table.addEventListener("mousedown", (e)=>{
    press =1;
    dx = e.x;
    dy = e.y;
    e.currentTarget.addEventListener("mousemove", function move(e){
        if(press==1){
            e.x = e.x - dx;
            e.y = e.y - dy;
            e.currentTarget.style.transform = `translateX(${e.clientX-0.5*e.currentTarget.offsetWidth}px) translateY(${e.clientY-0.5*e.currentTarget.offsetHeight}px)`;
        }
...

Comment: Вот типичный код для любого drag'n'drop https://jsfiddle.net/mrce580L/

Comment: @ᅠhᅠспасибо, впервые про getBoundingClientRect() слышу.

Comment: Не за что. Ещё можно добавить в фукцию `onMouseDown` - `e.preventDefault()`, чтобы, например, если в этом блоке лежит фотография - она не drag'алась(хз как это на русском обозвать)